# NSTableView Drag & Drop not working inside of an NSCollectionViewItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstableview, nscollectionviewitem

I have a `NSCollectionView` and inside of the `NSCollectionViewItems` there is a label and a `NSTableView`.  The `NSTableViews` are working properly EXCEPT for the drag & drop methods (`tableView:writeRowsWithIndexes:toPasteboard:`, `tableView:validateDrop:proposedRow:proposedDropOperation:`, and `tableView:acceptDrop:row:dropOperation:`).  I have these working fine in other views, but I am not able to get them working inside of a `NSCollectionViewItem`.  Is there a different trick that needs to be used for drag & drop for a `NSTableView` inside of a `NSCollectionViewItem`?

Comment: Does your table view have its data source set?

Comment: I am having the same problem , were you able to resolve this issue?